# How to handle Authentication by API-Key or User credentials in a .net core API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant application, and for that I've developed a .Net Core API and so far I'm using JWT authentication so users have access to API Endpoits. My challenge starts when I want to validate access to endpoits of requests coming from another third party application that does not require credentials (user and password) so that it just passes the key of the tenant and that it was allocated for consumption of the API. How can I implement authentication by user credentials or APIKey?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer in the question. Use JWT.

Comment: Well! I figured out it. I implemented new controllers without authorization to handle request of third part software.  The third part software must supply The tenant Id and tenant APIKey. I'm still looking for the best practices.